# request with json data and multipart using afnetworking

Tags: php, ios, json, multipartform-data, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 and need to construct the request to my server with json data and multi images at the same time.

What i could image is the request will be in the following structure:

```
Content-Type    multipart/form-data;boundary=abc

--abc

{"title":"Product discussion","attendee":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"}]}

--abc

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="img"
Content-Type: image/png

...image data...

--abc--
```

Here is only the simplified structure. The real meeting data is much more complex with more hierarchies, so i think it's better to use json.

However I don't know how can build such data structure using afnetworking e.g.

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[parameters setValue:meeting.title forKey:@"title"];

NSMutableArray *attendeeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(Attendee *attendee in meeting.attendeeList)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *attendeeDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [attendeeDictionary setValue:attendeeID forKey:@"id"];
    [attendeeList addObject: attendeeDictionary];
}
[parameters setValue:attendeeList forKey:@"attendee"];

httpClient.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[httpClient POST:@"createappointment.php" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                    name:@"img"
                                fileName:@"img.png"
                                mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }

 } success:....
```

but the code seems to ignore the AFJSONRequestSerializer and puts the meeting title and attendee IDs in the form of the POST array.

On the server side is PHP. Normally I can get the image from $_FILE and the json data from php://input + json_decode, but in this case i don't know, what the the best way to parse the above structure?

Is there anyone also met such requirement and how to solve it correctly on iOS as well as server side?

Answer (score 0):

So in this case you get it from `$_POST` instead of `$_FILES` or you can use `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Comment: I cannot put the json data in $_POST, and "php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data"(http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)